# Syntax for importing function from object in class (Python 2)

Tags: python, import

I want to be able to access the strptime function directly (no `datetime.datetime.strptime()` or `datetime.strptime()`.)

I can do this:

```
from datetime import datetime
strptime = datetime.strptime
```

But is there a way to accomplish the same thing on the import line?

Also, can you do multiple items on one line?

Here's pseudocode of what I really want to do:

```
from datetime.datetime import strftime, strptime
```

Datetime is just the example case, a similar thing would be useful for importing class methods in other libraries.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with what you *can* do.

Comment: If you don't like typing many characters, you can use `from datetime import datetime as d`.

Comment: Was just more curious about the syntax of import than this particular case. Imagine there's something like `from mylibrary import myclass.mysubclass.dataEngine.something_Else.aFunctionINeed`...

Comment: So the answer is no. AFAIK. `from mylibrary import myclass` `spam=myclass.mysubclass.dataEngine.something_Else.aFunctionINeed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are methods of the `datetime` type and can't be imported directly.  You can't directly import anything below the top-level namespace of a module.  From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement):

> The `from` form does not bind the module name: it goes through the list of identifiers, looks each one of them up in the module found in step (1) [i.e., the module being imported], and binds the name in the local namespace to the object thus found.

That is, the imported names must be names in the *module* namespace.  They can't be any more deeply nested than that.  So you can't, as you apparently want to do, import just certain methods of classes in the module.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question "Can I do this on the import line?" is no.

See the [definition of the import statement in Python 2](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement).  The statement imports things from modules.  There is a `datetime` class inside the `datetime` module.  The best you can do is

```
from datetime import datetime
```

You already understand well what this does, as you used it perfectly in your question.  It looks like you wanted to do

```
from datetime import datetime.strptime
```

but that is a syntax error because `datetime.strptime` is not an indentifier.

You can't say

```
from datetime.datetime import strptime
```

either because Python would look for a *module* named `datetime.datetime`.

The import statement just doesn't work the way you want it to.

Note that the author of the `datetime` module chose to make `strptime` a **classmethod** (using `@classmethod`) rather than a function.  So if you want to use `strptime` without the class qualifier you will have to do what you did, namely assign to a variable named `strptime`.